# Create multiple lists and store them into a dictionary Python

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, iteration, defaultdict

Here's my situation. I got two lists:

- A list which comes from DF column (OS_names)
- A list with the unique values of that column (OS_values)

  OS_name = df['OS_name'].tolist()

  OS_values = df.OS_name.unique().tolist()

I want to create several lists (one per value in OS_values) like this :

```
t = []

for i in range(0,len(OS_name)-1):
    if OS_values[0] == OS_name[i]:
        t.append(1)
    else:
        t.append(0)
```

I want to create a list per each value in OS_value, then store them into a dictionary, and at the end creating a df from my dictionary.
If you're able to insert the value as the key it would be great, but not necessary.
I read the defaultdict may be helpful but I cannot find a way to use it.

thanks for the help and have a great day!

Comment: Would you be able to provide some example input/output? I'm having a little trouble understanding your snipplet/objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it at the very end.

```
dict_stable_feature = dict()

for col in df_stable:
    
    t1 = df[col].tolist()
    t2 = df[col].unique().tolist()
    
    for value in t2:
        
        t = []
        
        for i in range (0, len(t1)-1):
            
            if value == t1[i]:
                
                t.append(1)
            
            else:
                
                t.append(0)
                
        cc = str(col)
        vv = "_" + str(value)
        cv = cc + vv
        
        dict_stable_feature[cv] = t
```