# Creating a pyspark dataframe from a python dictionary

Tags: string, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a pyspark dataframe from a python dictionary but the following code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

df_stable = spark.createDataFrame(dict_stable_feature)
df_stable.show()
```

show this error

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>
```

Reading this post on stackoverflow:

[Pyspark: Unable to turn RDD into DataFrame due to data type str instead of StringType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463647/pyspark-unable-to-turn-rdd-into-dataframe-due-to-data-type-str-instead-of-strin)

I can deduce that maybe the problem is that I used by mistake python standard str instead of StringType and spark doesn't like it.
What can I do to make it work??

**EDIT:**

I created my dictionary using this code

[Create multiple lists and store them into a dictionary Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051520/create-multiple-lists-and-store-them-into-a-dictionary-python)

as you can see, the key is created doing

```
cc = str(col)
vv = "_" + str(value)
cv = cc + vv

dict_stable_feature[cv] = t
```

while `t` is just a binary list of `1` and `0`.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the values of each key in your dictionary? Are they scalar/single values or are they complex types such as lists/objects? Should each key be a new column in your dataframe or a value in a row ? Can you share a sample code with your dictionary and what your expected dataframe table should look like?

Comment: I posted some other info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with converting your python dictionary into a list of list values in the correct position (i.e. one of the expected data structures for initializing a spark dataframe).

You may try the following assuming all list values in dictionary are of the same length.

```py
column_names = []
dataset = None
for column_name in dict_stable_feature:
    column_names.append(column_name)
    column_values = dict_stable_feature[column_name]
    # initialize dataset ranges
    if dataset is None:
        dataset=[]
        
        for i in range(0,len(column_values)):
            dataset.append([column_values[i]])
    else:
        for ind,val in enumerate(column_values):
            dataset[ind].append(val)

my_df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(dataset,schema=column_names)
```

if all list values are not of the same length, then you may try the following:

```py
max_list_length = max([len(dict_stable_feature[k]) for k in dict_stable_feature])
column_names = []
dataset = [[] for i in range(0,max_list_length)]
default_data_value = None # feel free to change
for column_name in dict_stable_feature:
    column_names.append(column_name)
    column_values = dict_stable_feature[column_name]


    for ind,val in enumerate(column_values):
        dataset[ind].append(val)

    # ensure all columns have the same amount of rows
    no_of_values = len(column_values)
    if  no_of_values < max_list_length:
        for i in range(no_of_values,max_list_length):
            dataset[i].append(default_data_value)

my_df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(dataset,schema=column_names)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: the first one works! Just what I was looking for! thanks!